# Is there a way to set the width parameter in println! with a variable?

Tags: rust, format, printf

In C you can use set printf's width parameter dynamically like this:

```
printf("%*.*f", width, precision, value);
```

This is how I would like it to work:

```
let width = 8;
let precision = 2;
let value = 1234.56789;
println!("{:*.*}", width, precision, value);
```

But using that syntax throws `expected '}' in format string`.

This kind of works:

```
let width = 8;
let precision = 2;
let value = 1234.56789;
println!("{:8.*}", precision, value);
```

But as you can see the width is not set dynamically. I assume it doesn't work because of some good reason. Is it possible to make it work in a similar way or are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write:

```
fn main() {
    let width = 8;
    let precision = 2;
    let value = 1234.56789;
    println!("{:width$.precision$}", value);
}
```

This avoids mixing the actual values to be formatted with the formatting parameters, which I think is nice.

You can also write:

```
fn main() {
    let width = 8;
    let precision = 2;
    let value = 1234.56789;
    println!("{:1$.2$}", value, width, precision);
}
```

Or:

```
fn main() {
    let width = 8;
    let precision = 2;
    let value = 1234.56789;
    println!("{:foo$.bar$}", value, foo = width, bar = precision);
}
```

Comment: Although this works, I don't understand how it is possible: shouldn't macro hygiene prevent `println!` from accessing `width` and `precision` in the first example?

Comment: It isn't a macro but a compiler built-in.

Comment: @Acorn It is a compiler built-in macro. But even not built-in proc-macros don't have hygiene (by default).